# PHP failed to open Stream no such file or directory when trying to execute a php file

Tags: php, command-line

I keep getting:

`failed to open Stream: No such file or directory " Path " on line 2`

When I try to run this php file from the command line.

```
require_once 'modules/Reports/ScheduledReports.php'
VTScheduledReport::runScheduledReports($adb);
```

I have checked to see if the file is there and there is a class called class `VTScheduledReport` in `ScheduledReports.php` and the function `runScheduledReports`. Is there. The function looks like this:

```
public static function runScheduledReports($adb) {
    require_once 'modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTWorkflowUtils.php';
    $util = new VTWorkflowUtils();
    $adminUser = $util->adminUser();

    global $currentModule, $current_language;
    if(empty($currentModule)) $currentModule = 'Reports';
    if(empty($current_language)) $current_language = 'en_us';

    $scheduledReports = self::getScheduledReports($adb, $adminUser);
    foreach($scheduledReports as $scheduledReport) {
        $scheduledReport->sendEmail();
        $scheduledReport->updateNextTriggerTime();
    }
    $util->revertUser();
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this won't run?

Comment: Check your includes path in your php.ini file - this could be causing the script to look somewhere other than where you expect.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change

```
require_once 'modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTWorkflowUtils.php';
```

to

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/com_vtiger_workflow/VTWorkflowUtils.php');
```

if your include file path is relative to the script. `dirname(__FILE__)` return the full path of the file from where it is called.

for the `ScheduledReports.php` you can use the following

```
require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/modules/Reports/ScheduledReports.php');
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507